# Azure Remote Desktop - Access Denied

Tags: azure, active-directory, rdp

I'm currently facing an Access Denied error while connecting to an Azure VM. This VM is registered in an Active Directry. When I log with the AD credentials, I get an "Access Denied" error message with a "Ok" button without any other text on the screen. I never faced this issue before. The maching was working perfectly last week...

Do you have any idea about this issue ?

Thanks for your help

[Access Denied Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GevfJ.jpg)

Comment: You can try the troubleshooting steps in this article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-troubleshoot-remote-desktop-connections/ according to your VM's deployment model

Answer (score 0):

Can you still access the VM and its using your Azure Portal login? If so, try adding the AD user via RDP.

1. Go to Computer Mgmt on the VM via Remote Desktop
2. Expand the list of Remote Desktop Users.
3. Select the user(s) to add.

See details in the MSDN thread:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ebce1bb-2aa0-4bb0-adc7-d1e229c5ee9e/add-user-to-remote-desktop-group-in-azure-vm?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

If you're having RDP issues with the primary user account, check the Settings blade of your VM in the Azure Portal, and look at the Users list under Resource Management.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case it was related to Terminal Service Licensing.

First save a local copy of the RDP file from the portal and run this command at a PowerShell command prompt to connect. This will disable licensing for just that connection:

```
mstsc <File name>.RDP /admin
```

after you are able to connect then open the Event Viewer an look for an Event with ID 4105 in WIndows Logs > System. this event should appear every time a logging was attempted.

If that is the case, follow this steps to solve the issue

[Event ID 4105 — Terminal Services Per User Client Access License Tracking and Reporting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775179(v=ws.10).aspx)

Hope this helps.